# how to make javascript to only count the second?

Tags: javascript

I have found the following script online that it is very useful to countdown time, but I only want to count seconds, e.g count 86400 seconds instead of 10days. If I divide the 60 at the first one, it will calculate the seconds correctly, and show the number, however, it is static and not moving since second should be change every second.How can I achieve that? I don't understand why it divide 1000 at the beginning either because I don't know what is the current_date format. Appreciate helps.

```js
// set the date we're counting down to
var target_date = new Date("Jul 10, 2016").getTime();
 
// variables for time units
var days, hours, minutes, seconds;
 
// get tag element
var countdown = document.getElementById("countdown");
 
// update the tag with id "countdown" every 1 second
setInterval(function () {
 
    // find the amount of "seconds" between now and target
    var current_date = new Date().getTime();
    var seconds_left = (target_date - current_date) / 1000;
 
    // format countdown string + set tag value
    countdown.innerHTML =  seconds_left + "s";  
 
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="countdown"></div>
```

Comment: The divide by 1000 is because getTime() returns miliseconds

Comment: Theoretically, this question deserves no answer, since there is not a single spark of effort to be seen to solve the problem of your own...seriously...

Comment: This line: `var seconds_left = (target_date - current_date) / 1000;` is already doing what you want. If you don't need hours:minutes:seconds then just get rid of the code related to that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```js
// set the date we're counting down to
var target_date = new Date("Aug 15, 2019").getTime();
 
// variables for time units
var days, hours, minutes, seconds;
 
// get tag element
var countdown = document.getElementById("countdown");
 
// update the tag with id "countdown" every 1 second
setInterval(function () {
 
    // find the amount of "seconds" between now and target
    var current_date = new Date().getTime();
    var seconds_left = (target_date - current_date) / 1000;
 
    // format countdown string + set tag value
    countdown.innerHTML =  seconds_left + "s";  
 
}, 1000);
```

Function getTime() returns milisecond, therfore it is divided by 1000 to get seconds.

Comment: Correct! You beat me for 39 seconds ;-)

Comment: by the way, how to remove the milliseond

Comment: countdown.innerHTML = Math.round(seconds_left) + 's';

Answer (score 2):

You only need the `seconds_left` part, without the decimals, to get a countdown in seconds from the target date:

```
// set the date we're counting down to
var target_date = new Date("Aug 15, 2019").getTime();

// get tag element
var countdown = document.getElementById("countdown");

// update the tag with id "countdown" every 1 second
setInterval(function () {

// find the amount of "seconds" between now and target
var current_date = new Date().getTime();
var seconds_left = (target_date - current_date) / 1000;

// round the result
countdown.innerHTML = seconds_left|0;

}, 1000);
```